# Microsoft.Web.Administration connect to server with a specific account

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I am developing a small webappication for other developers so that they can stop and start IIS application-pools on four servers.
The assembly ***Microsoft.Web.Administration*** provides this functionality.
How can I connect with this library to another server with **another** user? I found the method to connect to a server, but unfortunately without user or password:

```
using(ServerManager sm = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
{
...
}
```

Thanks a lot for any hints.

Comment: You need to set the application pool identity to a suitable account.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. There are 4 servers to manage. Is it possible to switch user in case there is a different service-account for each machine?

Comment: Instead of calling C# API, write a few PowerShell scripts and then call them via C# where you can pass different user credentials to `Invoke-Command`.